# owncloud list external storage (error 503)

Tags: python, python-2.7, owncloud, cloud-storage

When trying to list the files of an external storage using the [pyocclient](https://github.com/owncloud/pyocclient) my owncloud server returns a 503 http status code, with the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<d:error xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns" xmlns:d="DAV:">

<s:exception>Sabre\DAV\Exception\ServiceUnavailable</s:exception>

<s:message>Storage not available</s:message>

</d:error>
```

this is the code I use, it works perfectly on normal folders:

```
url = 'https://drive.xxxxxx.xx/'
webdavRoot = 'remote.php/webdav'
oc = owncloud.Client(url, verify_certs=False)

oc.login('xxxx', 'xxxx')

listFiles = oc.list('/HomeDrive (H)/')
```

When using the following code it does work:

```
for item in listFiles:
    list.append(item.get_path())
print list
test = oc.list(list[3])
print test
```

after some more testing, it seems that I first have to do a list requests to the root folder before it works. But doing this is an extra request which really slows down my code. Is there a way around this?

verify_certs is False, because I use Fiddler to check the requests.

Comment: Get_stroage_by_id, Get_stroage_by_name, permission ?

Comment: The problem is not permission, I did some more testing and when I get the path from a list request of '/' and it does work.

Comment: Edited the question after some more research